# Create a chartjs pie chart using json data

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

Im trying to display multiple charts using chartjs. I have a working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f0rtunaMajor/d7v88w64/) with a hard coded multiple data. How do I achieve the same result using a retrieved json data from my controller? How do I push the retrieved json data as my chart's dataset?

This is the json data being returned from my controller:

```
[{"countAgree":1,"countSomewhatAgree":0,"countDisagree":1},
{"countAgree":0,"countSomewhatAgree":1,"countDisagree":1},
{"countAgree":0,"countSomewhatAgree":1,"countDisagree":1}]
```

I tried doing the following but the charts are not being created:

```
var charts = "myCharts";

var jsonData = [];

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Controller/GetData',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(obj, function (i, data) {
            jsonData.push({ data: [data[i].countAgree, data[i].countSomewhatAgree, data[i].countDisagree] });
        });
        //create chart
    }
});
```

I also tried

```
$.getJSON("/Controller/GetData", function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
        jsonData.push({ data: [data[i].countAgree, data[i].countSomewhatAgree, data[i].countDisagree] });
    }

    //create charts
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the structure of the data after working on it in the loop

Change the loop to the following:

```
$.each(obj, function (i, data) {
   jsonData.push({ A: data.countAgree, B: data.countSomewhatAgree, C: data.countDisagree, Q: 'Question' + (i + 1) });
});
```